# opengl es 2.0 glsl gl_FragCoord not accurate?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to draw a red rectangle in my fragment shader, however its height is being drawn slightly more then it should sometimes 10 to 20 pixels more... im using this condition for the draw, is this a wrong way to do it?

```
if( gl_FragCoord.x > tagRect.x 
    && gl_FragCoord.x <= (tagRect.x + tagRect.z) 
    &&  gl_FragCoord.y > tagRect.y 
    && gl_FragCoord.y <= (tagRect.y + tagRect.w))
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

where tagRect is a vec4 structure defining the rectangle coord x,y and dimensions w,h

Comment: You should definitly make usage of the vertexshader too, by just giving the vertexshader a quad which will be drawn red. gl_FragCoord is the fragmentposition after transformations and interpolations are done by the vertex shader. Maybe your vertexshader transforms different some times.

Comment: my vertexshader is basic and just multiplies the vertex coordinates (fetched from a vbo) with the model view projection matrix which is a fixed orthogonal matrix. "gl_Position = myMVPMatrix * myVertex;", so it's not possible that is differing some times. there must be something else...